# Css3: Hover on div1 to create reaction in div 2 & 3?

Tags: css, hover, margin

I'm trying to create an animation whereby hovering over the top div will trigger a reaction in the below div's.

What I am hoping to achieve is the flow-on effect where by hovering on any individual `<span>` on the top row will trigger the bottom rows to also push down.

The original CSS isn't my creation, I've simply built/edited on top of pre-existing work.

/* animation2.css */

```
#preloader_4{
     position:relative;
    }

#preloader_4 span{
     margin-top: 6.4%;
     position:absolute;
     width:8em;
     height:8em;
     background:#3498db;
     opacity:0.8;
     border-radius:8em;
     transition-property: margin-top;
     transition-timing-function: ease;
     transition-duration: 0.8s; 
    }

#preloader_4 span:hover{
     margin-top:7.5%;     
    }    

#preloader_4 span:nth-child(2){
    left:8em;
    animation-delay: .2s;
}
#preloader_4 span:nth-child(3){
    left:16em;
    animation-delay: .2s;
}


/* Smaller circles */


#preloader_3{
     position:relative;
    }
#preloader_3 span{
     margin-top: 3.0%;
     position:absolute;
     width:4em;
     height:4em;
     background:#9d4abf;
     opacity:0.9;
     border-radius:4em;
     left:4em;
     transition-property: margin-top;
     transition-timing-function: ease;
     transition-duration: 0.5s; 
    }    

#preloader_3 span:hover{
     margin-top: 4.5%;
    }        

#preloader_3 span:nth-child(2){
    left:8em;
    animation-delay: .1s;
}
#preloader_3 span:nth-child(3){
    left:12em;
    animation-delay: .1s;
}
#preloader_3 span:nth-child(4){
    left:16em;
    animation-delay: .1s;
}
#preloader_3 span:nth-child(5){
    left:20em;
    animation-delay: .1s;
}


/* Smallest Green circles */

#preloader_2{
     position:relative;
    }
#preloader_2 span{
     margin-top: 1%;
     position:absolute;
     width:2em;
     height:2em;
     background:#6ee3dd;
     opacity:1.0;
     border-radius:2em;
     left:4em;
     transition-property: margin-top;
     transition-timing-function: ease;
     transition-duration: 0.3s; 
    }
#preloader_2 span:hover{
     margin-top:1.5%; 
    }    

#preloader_2 span:nth-child(2){
    left:4em;
    animation-delay: .0s;
}
#preloader_2 span:nth-child(3){
    left:6em;
    animation-delay: .0s;
}
#preloader_2 span:nth-child(4){
    left:8em;
    animation-delay: .0s;
}
#preloader_2 span:nth-child(5){
    left:10em;
    animation-delay: .0s;
}
#preloader_2 span:nth-child(6){
    left:12em;
    animation-delay: .0s;
}
#preloader_2 span:nth-child(7){
    left:14em;
    animation-delay: .0s;
}
#preloader_2 span:nth-child(8){
    left:16em;
    animation-delay: .0s;
}
#preloader_2 span:nth-child(9){
    left:18em;
    animation-delay: .0s;
}
#preloader_2 span:nth-child(10){
    left:20em;
    animation-delay: .0s;
}
#preloader_2 span:nth-child(11){
    left:22em;
    animation-delay: .0s;
}

<div id="preloader_2">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </div>

<div id="preloader_3">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>       
         </div>

<div id="preloader_4">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </div>        
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And what is your question ?

Comment: Sorry to confuse the point.   
What I am trying to do is create a flow-on effect. Whereby hovering over the first div (preloader_4) will trigger the other two divs to also react as if they themselves were being hovered over. 

My question is whether this is possible?

Comment: Your post was triaged as in need of improvement and I edited it as it came up for me to "help and improve" it, which I tried my best to do: Since you can use markup and some HTML in your text, you have to backquote inline HTML statements like `<span>` otherwise they will just not be displayed. You should also read [help→tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and shoiuld leave out chit-chat from future posts,

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tips Blackus, i'm pretty new to this but I'll go over the your to better appropriate the formatting of my questions in the future. Thanks for taking the time go go over this. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got what you want here. It is possible with jQuery.
You should use jquery's siblings() method here.
I would use it like this-

```
$('#preloader_2').hover(function() {
    $(this).siblings().css('//your code here');
});
```

Comment: Hey Sumi, thanks for your help. 
I'm unfamiliar with JQuery formatting & I've added your code into my css document but I don't think I'm formatting it correctly as I just get a blank document. Do I need to write my own function like in Php? E.g .hover(function(create margin bottom) {

Comment: Hey Sumi, Thanks again for your answer above. I'm going to do some research into jQuery and I'll come back to you when I do if I need to configure your suggestion.

Comment: Hey Sumi, I'm getting the hang of using jQuery siblings. Just one question, with the solution you put forward can you see a way to undo the hover effect? i.e. When no longer hovering do the siblings return to pre-hover status?

Comment: no, they dont. You have to to write additional code line and kind of manipulate what you want to achieve with minor changes.

Answer (score 0):

> What I am hoping to achieve is the flow-on effect where by hovering on any individual on the top row will trigger the bottom rows to also push down.

Give your top row: `pointer-events: none;`

Jquery: `$("buttom row").hover(function(){ ... });`

Comment: Hi Trung, 
Thanks for taking the time to go over this. I'm trialing your method and a few others now. I'll let you know how I go :)

Comment: Just one question what do you mean by 'top row'?

Comment: <div id="top"></div><div id="bottom"></div> ... You have to give both of them position: absolute; and z-index for #top is always higher than #bottom.